# adding an identifier in a model whether a certain column is duplicate

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble identifying whether a certain collection has a duplicate entry. And if it has a duplicate entry, it should add an identifier whether this case is a duplicate. I am looping the tasks table in my view.

I have a task table that looks like this

```
id case   name   status notes
1  232    task1   1     testnotes
2  233    task2   1     testnotes
3  232    task3   1     testnotes
```

I wanted my collection to look something like this.

```
id case   name   status notes         identifyDuplicate
1  232    task1   1     testnotes      232    
2  233    task2   1     testnotes      null
3  232    task3   1     testnotes      232
```

My Controller looks like this

```
  $tasks = Tasks::with('User')->get();
```

And in my Tasks Model. I added this

```
  public function identifyDuplicate() {
      
      return $this->Tasks->groupBy('case')->havingRaw('COUNT(case) > 1')->get();
      
    }
```

I tried this in my Tasks Model as well

```
public function identifyDuplicate() {
  
  $identifyDuplicate = Tasks::wherein('case', function ($query) {
      $query->select('case')->from('tasks')->groupBy('case')->havingRaw('COUNT(case) > 1');
  })->get();
  return $identifyDuplicate;

}
```

both getting `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax` whenever i do a foreach in my blade and for the

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)

{{$task->identifyDuplicate() }}

@endforeach
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CASE" is a reserved word in the SQL specification.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_keywords.asp for examples of SQL reserved words.

To use this, especially in your Raw statements, you should surround case with the appropriate field identifiers for your database.

- Backticks for MySQL - `case`
- Square brackets for SQL Server - [case]

e.g.

```
->havingRaw('COUNT(`case`) > 1');
```